# mysql update selected

Tags: mysql, selected

I have a mysql query that selects a number of records

```
SELECT
leads.Affiliate_ID,
leads.first_name,
leads.last_name,
leads.email,
leads.loan_purpose,
leads.home_tel,
leads.mobile_tel,
leads.postcode,
leads.house_num,
leads.app_time,
leads.new_application_date,
leads.payment_accepted,
leads.sms
FROM
leads
WHERE
leads.Affiliate_ID =  '23' AND
leads.sms IS NULL  AND
leads.payment_accepted IS NULL  AND
leads.new_application_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

how do I now update `leads.sms` to `1` on all selected records

Any help or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the data, you don't need to select the records using select statement. You need to put the condition using `WHERE` clause as shown below. Using `WHERE` clause, the records are updated for the row who satisfy that condition.

```
UPDATE
leads SET sms = 1
WHERE
Affiliate_ID =  '23' AND
sms IS NULL  AND
payment_accepted IS NULL  AND
new_application_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Also in your question at all places you have used `leads.FIELD_NAME`. When there is one table, you don't need to use table name before field name. Table name is needed when JOINS are used using two or more tables.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question well, try:

```
UPDATE
leads SET sms = 1
WHERE
Affiliate_ID =  '23' AND
sms IS NULL  AND
payment_accepted IS NULL  AND
new_application_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: so do i run that after if have processed the records

Comment: the update command doesn't depend on the select command so you can run it any time, try running your select first, observe the result, then run the update and run the select again then observe the result again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace everything before the WHERE by the standard [update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) :

```
update leads set sms=1
WHERE
leads.Affiliate_ID =  '23' AND
leads.sms IS NULL  AND
leads.payment_accepted IS NULL  AND
leads.new_application_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: thanks so it should look like <code>SELECT
leads.Affiliate_ID,
leads.first_name,
leads.last_name,
leads.email,
leads.loan_purpose,
leads.home_tel,
leads.mobile_tel,
leads.postcode,
leads.house_num,
leads.app_time,
leads.new_application_date,
leads.payment_accepted,
leads.sms
FROM
leads
update leads set sms=1
WHERE
leads.Affiliate_ID =  '23' AND
leads.payment_accepted IS NULL  AND
leads.sms IS NULL  AND
leads.new_application_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)</code> or should i do my select and prepossessing then run a new mysql command to update

Comment: just run the update command and it will update all the selected rows, so next time you execute your select it should return no rows cause sms column has been update (no longer null).

Comment: By the way, it's a good practice to test as you did with a select query just before you do the update, so you're sure of what rows you'll change.